# Como configurar o driver pdo_mysql no Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, doctrine

> LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Exceptions\DriverNotFound  : Driver [pdo_mysql] not supported.

*Meu arquivo de configuração database.php está da seguinte forma*:

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Bruno! Tudo bem?

Utilizo o pdo em um dos meus projetos e não precisei fazer essa configuração no database.php
Provavelmente essa configuração deve ser feita no apache. Chegou a verificar se o driver está sendo carregado?

Se ainda não fez, você pode verificar criando um phpinfo() no seu servidor. Se tiver configurado certinho, deve mostrar la

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia Thiago, agradeço sua ajuda, deu certo aqui. Vlw

Comment: Boa, Bruno!
Que bom que solucionou.